# Somando 5 variáveis ao vez de uma! PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou tendo um problema em minhas condições(if).
Note que sou muito novato em php/mysql, então esse é o motivo de possivelmente meu codico está uma bagunça, mas é possível entender-lo.

```
<?php
@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "vertrigo") or die(mysql_error()); //Database connexion
mysql_select_db("aeuhue") or die(mysql_error()); // Select DB

$ads01 = "Ola, anunciante 01!\n";
$ads02 = "Ola, anunciante 02!\n";
$ads03 = "Ola, anunciante 03!\n";
$ads04 = "Ola, anunciante 04!\n";
$ads05 = "Ola, anunciante 05!\n";

function ShowVar($var) { // Funcao para retornar o nome da menor variavel em vez do valor
    foreach($GLOBALS as $varName => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $varName;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$count01 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads01 FROM counters"));
$count02 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads02 FROM counters"));
$count03 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads03 FROM counters"));
$count04 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads04 FROM counters"));
$count05 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads05 FROM counters"));

echo "$count01[0] <br>"; // apenas para visualizar o valor sem precisar ir no phpmyadmin
echo "$count02[0] <br>";
echo "$count03[0] <br>";
echo "$count04[0] <br>";
echo "$count05[0] <br>";

echo "<br><br><br><br>";


$result = min($count01, $count02, $count03, $count04, $count05); // Seleciona as variaveis e verifica qual é o minimo
$a = ShowVar($result); // ShowVar ira voltar o nome da varivel com menor valor, se count03 for a menor, ele retornará "count03"

echo "<b>$a</b><br><br>"; // apenas para visualizar e ver se o if está correto.

if($a == 'count01') // Se a ShowVar($a) retornar 'count01', exiba o $ads01 e adicione uma visualização no ads01
    echo $ads01;
    mysql_query("UPDATE counters SET ads01 = ads01 + 1");

if($a == 'count02')
    echo $ads02;
    mysql_query("UPDATE counters SET ads02 = ads02 + 1");

if($a == 'count03')
    echo $ads03;
    mysql_query("UPDATE counters SET ads03 = ads03 + 1");

if($a == 'count04')
    echo $ads04;
    mysql_query("UPDATE counters SET ads04 = ads04 + 1");   

if($a == 'count05')
    echo $ads05;
    mysql_query("UPDATE counters SET ads05 = ads05 + 1");

?>
```

A ideia desse codico e exibir 5 anúncios de forma que todos tenham visualizações praticamente iguais, usando php e mysql.
Existe um mini contador em mysql.

**O problema:** As condições(if) parecem está de forma correta, mas toda vez que eu entro na pagina, são somadas UMA visualizações para TODAS colunas(ads01,ads02,ads03,ads04,ads05) na minha taabela em minha database. 
Onde o correto era somar apenas para a variável que estiver com menor valor.

Veja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os valores ganharam +1, onde somente o count03(ads03 na tabela) deveria ter somado +1.

Creio que seja algum problema no IF ou alguma falha no fechamento das mysql_query. help me?

Comment: Faltando `UPDATE` no código para tal

Comment: Onde tem `UPDATE` na sua página?

Comment: Do que se trata o UPDATE? sou novato :[

Comment: Update vai alterar o valor da coluna, no seu caso incrementar +1

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE counters SET ads02 = ads02 + 1");
Então o update vai atualizar todos os valores das colunas da tabela conters?

Comment: Porque no caso, eu queria só fosse alterado a coluna ads02 na tabela counters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para incrementar a coluna de menor valor:

```
function ShowVar($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $varName => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $varName;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$ads01 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads01 FROM counters"));
$ads02 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads02 FROM counters"));
$ads03 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads03 FROM counters"));
$ads04 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads04 FROM counters"));
$ads05 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ads05 FROM counters"));


$result = min($ads01, $ads02, $ads03, $ads04, $ads05);
$a = ShowVar($result);

$valor = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT $a FROM counters"));

$newValor=$valor[0]+1;

mysql_query("UPDATE counters SET $a='$newValor'");
```

> vai incrementar em +1 a coluna de menor valor. Caso as colunas tenham o mesmo valor, ela irá incrementar +1 na primeira coluna da tabela, depois na segunda coluna e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Com sua logica e pequenas modificações consegui o resultado que eu queria!!! além de ter deixado o código menor, muito obrigado :D